# What does {}. before a CSS Selector mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was working on some CSS files and I found this:

```
{}.foo { color: red }
```

Does anyone know why `{}.` works in Chrome, even though it is not a correct syntax? Is it just ignored, or does it mean something? I haven't found documentation about it.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrVAP/10945/) with my example.

```css
h1 {
  color: #f00;
}

{}.ll {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

<p class="ll">This is a demo app that shows how to Fiddle with Firefox OS using JSFiddle! Please fork me and make wonderful things</p>
```

Comment: Looks like a mistake. Invalid but ignored, and never caught.

Comment: Was this found in some "reputable" code or just some garbage from a random website?

Comment: Could be a similar thing to prepending `;` to an IIFE in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simply an empty declaration block.

```
{}.foo { color: red; }
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
{}

.foo { color: red; }
```

and this:

```
{ background-color: green; }

.foo { color: red; }
```

All of which render the same: The first declaration does nothing. The CSS parser simply ignores it.

> [**4.1.7 Rule sets, declaration blocks, and
>   selectors**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#rule-sets)
>
> The selector consists of everything up to (but not including) the
>   first left curly brace (`{`). A selector always goes together with a
>   declaration block. When a user agent cannot parse the selector, it
>   must **ignore** the selector and the following declaration block (if any)
>   as well.
>
> [**4.2 Rules for handling parsing
>   errors**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#parsing-errors)
>
> In some cases, user agents must ignore part of an illegal style sheet.
>   This specification defines **"ignore"** to mean that the user agent parses
>   the illegal part (in order to find its beginning and end), but
>   otherwise acts as if it had not been there.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why it's in the code sample you found, but it doesn't do anything useful.

It's not required to have whitespace between CSS rules:

```css
.a{color:red}.b{color:blue}.c{color:green}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

And rules (or delimiters) without an associated selector are just ignored:

```css
.a{color:red}{color:blue}.c{color:green}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

Put those together in your `{}.foo{color:red}`, and the leading `{}` becomes an empty rule block applying to no element; the parser proceeds on to treat `.foo{...}` as normal CSS applying to elements with class "foo".